# Databinding a class with boolean and text to XMAL

Tags: c#, xaml

### I submitted this accidently, I fixed it myself and wasn't going to submit after writing out the question. But have learnt from the comments, thanks!

I am trying to create a simple todo app in win8 and eventually want to hock it into ToDoIst API. 
I have created a simple task class to try and get my head around the databinding however I just can not get it to do what I want to do. I have used listboxes and other basic form elements.

### task.cs

```
class task
{
    private string content;
    private bool complete;

    public string Content
    {
        get {return content;}
        set { content = value; }
    }
    public bool Complete
    {
        get { return complete; }
        set { complete = value; }
    }

    public task(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
        Complete = false;
    }
}
```

### MainPage.xaml

And at the moment my XAML looks like this.

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="482,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="500">
        <ListView x:Name="LVtasks" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                        <RadioButton/>
                    </StackPanel>   
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </GridView>
```

I have put in some dummy data, 4 elements and when I run it, it comes up with 4 boxes with radio buttons however no text (there is space for the text) I am not sure how I would bind the bool?

I can not see what I am doing wrong. If anyone could help and point me in the right direction, I have searched a fair amount of tutorials and just can not figure it out.

Comment: Have you set your DataContext?

Comment: @devdigital in my Mainpage.cs Oh thank you!

Comment: I have set the data context  'LVtasks.DataContext = taskList;'@Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks a little strange, maybe this is what you want:

```
<ListView x:Name="LVtasks" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ToDoItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton GroupName="ToDos" Content="{Binding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding IsComplete}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Do you really want [radiobuttons](http://www.wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html)? I think you want [Checkboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox.aspx), the difference is that when you use radiobuttons only one in a group can be 'checked'

I used this code behind to have a datacontext:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

            ToDoItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>(new List<TodoItem>
                {
                    new TodoItem("Content1"),
                    new TodoItem("Content2")
                });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> ToDoItems { get; set; }
}
```

I changed the name of task to ToDoItem Task is already a class in the framework and might cause confusion.

Comment: Okay thank you, could you explain why you have used a Partial class? Trying to learn from your code. Many thanks!

Comment: In wpf windows are partial, one part is the Xaml and the other part is the code behind. I wrote it this way to have a quick sample you might want to extract most of the code to a viewmodel and a model. Dis you get it to run btw?

Comment: If you see my edit to my main question I fixed it before I submitted. An accident. However I am going to try and integrate your code. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the `RadioButton` `IsChecked` is the property to bind to a bool property:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Complete}"/>
```

Your text is most likely not showing up because you haven't set up any change notifications and the binding is happening before you set the `Content` values. Using the [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the most common and usually the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Could you maybe help me to how I would integrate that as I am finding it hard to do?

Answer (score 0):

Like John already mentioned you should really let the window containing your listview implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. And to set the data context of your window like Johan said. It is important that you call the propertychanged method in each setter of a property. It is also useful to use an ObservableCollection as ItemSource of your listview. Try to create an instance of ObservableCollection, create a property for it calling propertychanged method in its setter an set rhe ItemSource of your listview to the property. Do not forget to also call propertychanged whenever you add or remove items from the collection